# missing installation in TFS Agent Build

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have a VS(VS2015) solution which has 3 projects (2 SQL DB and 1 SSIS project). Our code repository in in TFS 2015/Git. There is no error or warning when I build the solution in VS. However when I tried to build it through TFS Agent which we can not skip for deployment, the SSIS project is missing in the installation. In the log file it shows a warning of expired license(screen-shot attached). I tried to run the TFS Agent on two different PCs (one with a free community version of vs2015 installed and another with a full enterprise license), but both got exactly the same issue.

I am not sure this it's really related to the VS license or some other issue in TFS Agent itself. BTW my TFS Agent seems running OK, I configure with cmd without error and I can queue builds without any issues.

Many thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SphH2.jpg)

Comment: The issue is exactly what the error message says. The license is expired.

Comment: Are you sure this warning is a licence issue ? The snapshot also shows `File does not indicate full path to a executable file`, which looks more like an error than a warning. Maybe you should check the path of the devenv executable on the agent (ex: Program Files(x86) vs Program Files etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. the issue has been rectified by reinstalling VS with a new license. btw, it still has the warning of "File does not indicate full path to a executable file", but no missing installation anymore.
Cheers